# What does the "yield" keyword do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, yield-keyword

I encountered the following Ruby code:

```
class MyClass
    attr_accessor :items
    ...
    def each
        @items.each{|item| yield item}
    end
    ...
end
```

What does the `each` method do? In particular, I don't understand what `yield` does.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is an example fleshing out your sample code:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :items

  def initialize(ary=[])
    @items = ary
  end

  def each
    @items.each do |item| 
      yield item
    end
  end
end

my_class = MyClass.new(%w[a b c d])
my_class.each do |y|
  puts y
end
# >> a
# >> b
# >> c
# >> d
```

`each` loops over a collection. In this case it's looping over each item in the `@items` array, initialized/created when I did the `new(%w[a b c d])` statement.

`yield item` in the `MyClass.each` method passes `item` to the block attached to `my_class.each`. The `item` being yielded is assigned to the local `y`.

Does that help?

Now, here's a bit more about how `each` works. Using the same class definition, here's some code:

```
my_class = MyClass.new(%w[a b c d])

# This points to the `each` Enumerator/method of the @items array in your instance via
#  the accessor you defined, not the method "each" you've defined.
my_class_iterator = my_class.items.each # => #<Enumerator: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]:each>

# get the next item on the array
my_class_iterator.next # => "a"

# get the next item on the array
my_class_iterator.next # => "b"

# get the next item on the array
my_class_iterator.next # => "c"

# get the next item on the array
my_class_iterator.next # => "d"

# get the next item on the array
my_class_iterator.next # => 
# ~> -:21:in `next': iteration reached an end (StopIteration)
# ~>    from -:21:in `<main>'
```

Notice that on the last `next` the iterator fell off the end of the array. This is the potential pitfall for *NOT* using a block because if you don't know how many elements are in the array you can ask for too many items and get an exception.

Using `each` with a block will iterate over the `@items` receiver and stop when it reaches the last item, avoiding the error, and keeping things nice and clean.

Comment: Did you meant Begin-End Block as stated [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm) . I am new to ruby so trying to find out what did you meant by block there.

Comment: You will also see `return to_enum(:each) unless block_given?` in `#each` which will return an `Enumerator` when no block is given allowing things such as `collection.each.take(10)`.

Answer (score 17):

When you write a method that takes a block, you can use the `yield` keyword to execute the block.

As an example, `each` could have been implemented in the Array class like this:

```
class Array
  def each
    i = 0
    while i < self.size
      yield( self[i] )
      i = i + 1
    end
  end
end
```

`MyClass#each` takes a block. It executes that block once for each item in the instance's `items` array, passing the current item as an argument.

It might be used like this:

```
instance = MyClass.new
instance.items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
instance.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```

Answer (score 10):

A Ruby method that receives a code block invokes it by calling it with the `yield` keyword. It can be used to iterate over a list but it is not a iterator like what you find in other some other languages.

[Here](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas) is a good explanation that explains it better than I would ever be able to.

Comment: fwiw - I found [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm) to give a simpler explanation of {code}yield{code} specifically

Answer (score 9):

According to my understanding yield executes code from block.

```
def name
    puts "A yield will be called with id of 12"
    yield 12
    puts "A yield will be called with id of 14"
    yield 14
end


name {|i| puts "I am called by yield name #{i}"}
```

Output:

A yield will be called with id of 12

I am called by yield name 12

A yield will be called with id of 14

I am called by yield name 14

**How yield works?**

So when the `name` function runs wherever yield comes the block code runs. Which is `name {|i| puts "I am called by yield name #{i}"}`

You can see that there is a word `yield 12` yield runs the code inside block passing 12 as value of `i`.

Here is a game example for it:

```
def load_game
    puts "Loading"

    yield

end


load_game { puts "Game loaded" }
```

This will print `game loaded` right after printing `loading`:

Loading

Game Loaded

Answer (score 6):

As a newbie, looking through a number of the answers confused me until I hit Abhi's answer.

the yield command pauses executing the code in the method, and instead passes control back to the block of code that called it, executes that code, and then continues executing the rest of the method after that.  Here's an example that clarified it for me:

```
def hello
    puts "hello"
    yield 
    puts "world"
end

hello do
    puts "there"
end
```

Output:

hello

there

world

Answer (score 5):

`yield` tells ruby to call the block passed to the method, giving it its argument.

`yield` will produce an error if the method wasn't called with a block where as `return` statement don't produces error.

`return` can only send single values where as `Yield` return object of huge values.

Answer (score 4):

The net effect is that calling .each on an instance of MyClass is the same as calling .each on the .items of that instance.

Answer (score 3):

As cpm said its taking the block and executing it

Simple example:

```
def my_method
  yield
end


my_method do
  puts "Testing yield"
end

Testing yield
=> nil
```